# git subtree split issues after svn2git migration

Tags: windows, git, git-subtree, svn2git

I have just converted a large nested SVN repo to git using the git2svn command line tool and now have a git repo at `D:\project`

Repo folder structure as follows:

```
\web\projectA
\web\projectB
\winforms\projectD
\winforms\projectE
```

I want to extract `\web\projectA` into a new git repo to upload to github.

After some research I have used `git subtree split --prefix=web\projectA -b justprojectA`

However the new branch after running the subtree command still contains all the folders from the root of the repo and doesn't seem to have worked at all.

I am using git shell on WIndows 7.

Comment: Ignore the folders.  Does the new branch contain *files* that it shouldn't?  If you push the new branch to a dedicated repository, does it look like you expect?

Comment: Yes it contains both directories and files that it should not.

Comment: I ended up pulling the new branch into a new repo and it showed the correct folder this time after the pull. So it worked after all. Thanks to @larsks for making me pull to a new repo.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up initializing a new empty repo and pulling the split branch into it. After I did that the new repo showed the correct root folder and files.